# How to download data from a series of pages?

Tags: openrefine

Example:

1. I want to download all data from https://www.example.com/api.php?id=X (fictitious URL), where X is 1 to 1000 and each page is a JSON containing data of a data row. (I don't want to manually add 1000 URLs and OpenRefine seems not allowing pasting list of URLs).
2. I want to download information in pages in
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_horror_films_by_year, each of which contains one HTML table.
3. I want to download data in all tables from all pages in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Earthquakes_by_year, each of which contains multiple HTML tables.

Answer (score 2):

OpenRefine is not a web scraping tool. It has the feature to fetch web pages, but you will hit a lot of limitation quickly.

Example 1 you can prepare your list of URL in a spreadsheet software like Excel or OpenOffice Calc. Import your project in OpenRefine and user the feature `Add a column by fetching URL`.

Example 2 and 3: OpenRefine cannot crawl or follow links. You will need to:

- extract the list of links from each page, using OpenRefine to
- creates a separated OpenRefine project with one link per row
- fetch each page using the `Add a column by fetching URL` feature
- parse the HTML of each page